# UIButton TouchUpInside Not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton

UIButton TouchUpInSide Not working, but on long press selector corresponding to TouchUpinside is getting called, and TouchDown is working fine. I google a lot to find the answer, but no luck. Hope this weird problem gets solved. Thank you.

Comment: Can u please show us your code for creating button..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TouchUpInside Action is getting override by a gesture Recognizer of the super class of the View Controller. Thanks you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TouchUpInside` or maybe `TouchUpOutside` instead of `TouchInUpSide`. Where did you find that action?...

Comment: Yes this is the right way @chad. On UIButton TouchUpInside works! +1 for it.

Comment: Guys that's a typo. Any way the TouchUpInside Action is getting overrided by a gesture Recogniser of the super class of the View Controller. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I don't see an UIControlEvent TouchInUpSide.

Use one of that list instead:

UIControlEventTouchDown
   UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat
   UIControlEventTouchDragInside
   UIControlEventTouchDragOutside
   UIControlEventTouchDragEnter
   UIControlEventTouchDragExit
   UIControlEventTouchUpInside
   UIControlEventTouchUpOutside
   UIControlEventTouchCancel

Answer (score 0):

You've to post the code and possibly explain the view hierarchy, so we can know about your code and who is the first responder. For security try another event and see what happen, it can be a spell error.